# amCharts 3 - Making labels appear in pie and stopping on click

Tags: javascript, html, json, amcharts, amcharts4

I have the following chart:

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "colorField": "color",
  "series": [{
    "type": "PieSeries",
    "alignLabels": false,
    "ticks": {
      "disabled": true
    },
    "labels": {
      "radius": "-40%",
      "fill": "white"
    }
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
      "title": "Yes",
      "value": 3,
      "color": "#6bbdb9"
    },
    {
      "title": "No",
      "value": 2,
      "color": "#2f2f2f"
    }
  ],

  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelRadius": 5,

  "radius": "42%",
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]",


  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.15/plugins/responsive/responsive.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I have two items I want to resolve:

1. I want the "Yes" and "No" labels to sit inside rather the slices, rather than be outside. From the [V4 docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/labels-inside-pie-chart-slices/), I have tried this approach:

   "series": [ {
     "type": "PieSeries",
     "alignLabels": false,
     "ticks": {
       "disabled": true
     },
     "labels": {
       "text": "{value.percent.formatNumber('#.0')}%",
       "radius": "-40%",
       "fill": "white"
     }
   }]

But this approach doesn't work for me in V3 (does nothing).

2. When you click a slice, it animates the slice outwards, I want, on click, for it to do nothing. Can't find anything on the docs about this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you're looking for is in the aptly named [Version 3 documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/); I'm not sure why you were poking around in the version 4 documentation.

That said, to move the labels inside, you need to set a negative [`labelRadius`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/ampiechart/#labelRadius_property) as demonstrated [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/pie-chart-labels-inside-slices/):

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  labelRadius: -35, //adjust as needed
  // ...
});
```

To disable the pull out on click, set [`pullOutRadius`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/ampiechart/#pullOutRadius_property) to 0.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  pullOutRadius: 0,
  // ...
});
```

Demo below:

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "colorField": "color",
  "dataProvider": [{
      "title": "Yes",
      "value": 3,
      "color": "#6bbdb9"
    },
    {
      "title": "No",
      "value": 2,
      "color": "#2f2f2f"
    }
  ],

  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelRadius": -35,

  "radius": "42%",
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]",
  "color": "#ffffff",
  "pullOutRadius": 0,


  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.15/plugins/responsive/responsive.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the "labelRadius" to a value lower than zero like "-35".

```
this.chart = this.AmCharts.makeChart('amchart-3', {
        'type': 'pie',
        "export": {
            "enabled": true,
            "menu": [ {
              "class": "export-main",
              "menu": [{
                        "format": "JPG",
                        "label": "Guardar como JPG",
                        "title": "Exportar gráfica a formato JPG",
                        'fileName': "Estadisticas  de planes de carga",
                    },{
                        "format": "PNG",
                        "label": "Guardar como PNG",
                        "title": "Exportar gráfica a formato PNG",
                        'fileName': "Estadisticas  de planes de carga",
                    }]
            } ]
        },
        "hideCredits": true,
        'dataProvider': this.datos,
        'titleField': 'townName',
        'valueField': 'tPlanes',
        'labelRadius': -35,
        'radius': '46%',
        'labelText': 'Planes [[value]] - fecha: [[title]]',
        'adjustPrecision': true,
        'angle': 30,
        "depth3D": 15,
        'marginRight': 40,
        'marginTop': 30,
        'marginBottom': 30,
        'fontSize': 10,
        'outlineAlpha': 1,
        'outlineThickness': 1,
        "legend":{
            "enabled": true,
            "position": "right",
            "divId": "legenddiv"
       },
       'balloonText': 'Total de planes: [[value]]  Fecha: [[title]]',
       "balloon": {
            "drop": true,
            "adjustBorderColor": false,
            "color": "#FFFFFF",
            "fontSize": 10,
            'maxWidth': 75,
        },
    });
```

In this example im using Angular and changed some atributtes